# Script runs perfectly in all other browsers but IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This block of code works perfectly fine in all other browsers. It DOES work in IE when I do a hard refresh of the page, but NOT when going to the page again thereafter. I have no idea why. Any incite would be greatly helpful.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {

/// func auto-sets the yellow and red values for mean and median respectfully
function calculateGoals(goal, yellow, red) {

    $(document.body).on('input', goal, function () {

        var g = $(goal), y = $(yellow), r = $(red); //set up the selectors

        y.val(parseFloat(g.val()) + 0.001);
        r.val(parseFloat(g.val()) + parseFloat(g.val()) * 0.2);
        y.attr('value', parseFloat(g.val()) + 0.0001);
        r.attr('value', parseFloat(g.val()) + parseFloat(g.val()) * 0.2);

    });
}

/// call the funcs for mean and median
calculateGoals('.mean-goal', '.mean-yellow', '.mean-red');
calculateGoals('.median-goal', '.median-yellow', '.median-red');
}
```

The script takes the input from '.mean-goal' and changes the other values accordingly on user input.

JS Fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/Jn52h/](http://jsfiddle.net/Jn52h/1/) - It seems to work perfectly fine, even in IE. But on my dev environment, it doesn't work after you reload the page (after a soft refresh).

Comment: what doesn't work - do you get a script error, or does nothing happen, etc? Does this only happen during development (IE cache can be a killer!), or only on deployment?

Comment: Where does it stop? why doesn't it work? the browser being IE isn't reason enough for us to help you fix it. What version of IE? I don't think the input event is supported in all versions of IE, but if it wasn't supported in your version, a hard refresh wouldn't change the outcome.

Comment: There is no script error. I'm only in a development environment. It doesn't do what you would expect it to do, which is change the corresponding values on user input...

Comment: jsFiddle + browser version you see this in would help.

Comment: "It doesn't do what you would expect it to do" - could you explain what it *is* expected to do, and what it does in the non-working case, and also put this on http://jsfiddle.net/ as we can't test this ourselves without the supporting markup...

Comment: JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jn52h/ - It seems to work perfectly fine, even in IE. But on my dev environment, it doesn't work after you reload the page (after a soft refresh).

Comment: New jsfiddle without the alerts: http://jsfiddle.net/Jn52h/1/

Comment: Odd. What version of IE is it? Could you try moving the function calls to `$(document).ready()` just in case it's some weirdness with the IE DOM? (as though that would be a great surprise to anyone :)

Comment: Tried that, didnt work :( Im using IE10 atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. In case anyone runs into this problem, simply change the 'input' func type to 'keyup' for this kind of problem:

```
$(document.body).on('keyup', goal, function () {
```

IE sucks.